# Understanding "話之"

Tags: meaning, cantonese

> CantoDict: [話之](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4820/)
>
> regardless of; no matter what; "I don't care" | Std. Chin.: 不管; 無論 | Syn.: 唔理 | Usu. in the form of 話之你; 話之佢 etc.

~

> 粵典: [話之 / 話知](https://words.hk/zidin/v/86577/%E8%A9%B1%E4%B9%8B/%E8%A9%B1%E7%9F%A5)
>
> (yue) 唔理唔顧；無視
>
> (eng) to ignore; to disregard; not to care; not to give a damn; used to >express indifference on the part of the speaker

Example of 話之 in a sentence:

- **話之**佢死，最緊要我地走得甩 - **Don't care** if he would die, the most important thing is we can escape
- 我**話之**你係皇帝，冇位就係冇位 - I **don't care** if you were the emperor, If there's no seat, there's no seat.

> My thinking is:
>
> "話" = "say"
>
> "之" = "it"
>
> "話之" = "say it"
>
> "say it" --> suppose --> suppose (whoever) are (whatever), I don't care

replace "don't care" with "say it" in English:

- **話之**佢死，最緊要我地走得甩 - **Say** if he would die, the most important thing is we can escape
- 我**話之**你係皇帝，冇位就係冇位 - I **say** if you were the emperor, If there's no seat, there's no seat.

Question: Does is make sense that it is how we break down "話之" (say it = suppose = don't care)? Or there's some other explanation?

Comment: If you do interpret it this way, then you'll have to treat 話知 as an "incorrect" way of writing it.

Comment: Yes, if my interpretation is correct, then "話知" (say knowing) would also be a valid form of this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

i would treat it as “話知”:

i acknowledge (知道) from your speech (說話) that . . . **[but]**. . .

Comment: Are you suggesting “話知” is the original, standard term and  "話之" was a mistake, but became too popular and was accepted as a valid variant  of “話知”?. It could be an answer.

Comment: yes, imo, 話知 is the original. meanwhile, 話之 is acceptable, i would not say it’s a mistake. you know, write down the proper character for cantonese is, quite difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

After exchanging comments with 水巷孑蠻 I did further research and found this entry in CantoDict

> [*話知*](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/58523/): *used to express indifference on the part of the speaker*

It confirmed "話之' and "話知" are indeed variant of each other. The question is: "which is the original?"

Base on my interpretation of "話之": ["say it" --> suppose --> suppose (whoever) are (whatever), I don't care], "話知" being the original would make more sense ["say knowing" --> say knowing (whoever) are (whatever), I don't care]

The answer to my original question: "...Or there's some other explanation? " would be:

> “**話知**” was the original, standard term for the meaning of "**don't care**" in Cantonese. And "話之" was a wrong way to write it because 知 and 之 are pronounced the same in Cantonese (*Wayne Cheah suggested that people got lazy*). Eventually, "話之"  was accepted as a valid variant of “話知” by dictionaries due to it's popularity

Answer (score 1):

I think people got lazy as the 之 is easier and quicker to write than 知 and both sound exactly the same in Cantonese. In any case everybody knows what it means, so no problem.

It's like "Christmas" and "Xmas"